# Como registrar um log no PHP?

Tags: php

Tenho um código em php que fica fazendo verificações no servidor e quando ele está online ou offline ele retornar uma mensagem diferente:

```
<?php
$server='LOJA 01 - ';
  $conectado = @ fsockopen('10.200.0.100', 135, $numeroDoErro, $stringDoErro, 1); // Este último é o timeout, em segundos
  if ($conectado) {
    echo "<font size=0> $server <img src=Verde.png height=8 width=8> </font>";
  } else {
    echo "<font size=0> $server <img src=Vermelho.png height=8 width=8> </font>";
  } 

?>
```

Gostaria de saber se quando ele retornar a segunda condição se o PHP pode gravar a data e a hora que aconteceu num local, que pode ser num `syslog`, o local poderia ser no servidor mesmo como arquivo.. Na verdade eu gostaria que ele guardasse a data e hora em que deu erro para eu saber desde que horas aquele link está fora...

Comment: Onde você quer guardar esse log? Qual local? Como um arquivo, no syslog? Como você irá analisá-lo depois ?

Comment: pode ser num syslog, o local poderia ser no servidor mesmo como arquivo.. Na verdade eu gostaria que ele guardasse a hora em que deu erro para eu saber desde que horas aquele link está fora...

Comment: Legal Igor, recomendo [edit] sua pergunta e colocar o que você disse no comentário para ajudar quem no futuro chegar até aqui. Sua pergunta está boa mas pode melhorar em alguns pontos. Leitura recomendada: [mcve] e [tour]

Comment: Desnecessário o fechamento da pergunta. A pergunta está simples e clara. Uma forma de resolver é usando a função nativa `error_log('mensagem aqui', 3, '/onde/salvar/arquivo.log');`. Consulte: http://php.net/error_log

Comment: Uma função do próprio PHP pode ser muito útil para isso. http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.error-log.php

Comment: Não precisa colocar "resolvido", basta apenas marca aquela resposta que resolveu o problema o sinal verde. Mais detalhes em: [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/91)

Comment: Estou pondo um bônus para a resposta do @GuilhermeNascimento, que entendo usar o recurso correto para o que foi pedido.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Faz assim , usa essa função

```
function logMe($msg){
// Abre ou cria o arquivo bloco1.txt
// "a" representa que o arquivo é aberto para ser escrito
$fp = fopen("log.txt", "a");

// Escreve a mensagem passada através da variável $msg
$escreve = fwrite($fp, $msg);

// Fecha o arquivo
fclose($fp); -> OK
}
```

para usar

```
logMe("Msg que vc quer guardar no txt");
```

se vc ainda tiver dúvidas tem algo bem mais explicado aqui :

http://rberaldo.com.br/como-gerar-logs-execucao-php/

Comment: Muito obrigado!
Funcionou exatamente como eu queria!!!

Comment: fico feliz em saber que ajudei, entendeu como funciona o processo?

Comment: não esquece d marcar como concluido quando finalizar

Comment: Entendi sim!!!! 

Muito obrigado!!! Agora eu não sei como finalizar a pergunta :S Sou novato aqui!! rsrsrs

Answer (score 11):

Você pode usar uma função própria para isto, o [error_log](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php), ele basicamente grava os dados no arquivo definido no php.ini:

```
error_log('Erro customizado'); // mesmo que: error_log('Erro customizado', 0);
```

Mas se desejar gravar em um arquivo determinado pode usar assim (mudando o segundo parametro para `3`, por padrão ele é 0):

```
error_log('Erro customizado' . PHP_EOL, 3, '/home/usuario/meulogdeerror.log');
```

Em windows deve ser algo como:

```
error_log('Erro customizado' . PHP_EOL, 3, 'C:/wamp/log/meulogdeerror.log');
```

Você também pode querer enviar por e-mail, para isso use o parametro 1:

```
error_log('Erro customizado', 1, 'adm@examplo.com.br');
```

Note que neste caso é necessário configurar o quarto parâmetro chamado `$extra_headers`, esse ultimo parâmetro é só usado para o caso de emails

> ```
> bool error_log ( string $message [, int $message_type = 0 [, string $destination [, string $extra_headers ]]] )
> ```

Você tem 4 tipos de log conforme configura o segundo parâmetro `$message_type`:

- `0` mensagem é enviada para o sistema de log do PHP, usando o sistema de log do sistema operacional ou para um arquivo, dependendo do que estiver definido na diretiva `error_log` no php.ini. Esta é a opção padrão.
- `1` mensagem é enviada para o endereço de email em `$destination`. Este é o único tipo de mensagem onde o quarto parâmetro `$extra_headers` é usado.
- `2` Não é mais uma opção, acredito que era usado suportado apenas no PHP3
- `3` mensagem é adicionada ao arquivo setado em `$destination`. Uma nova linha não é adicionada automaticamente ao final ao fim da string, o que pode fazer as mensagem ficarem na mesma linha, para isso você pode usar `PHP_EOL` como mostrei nos exemplos acima.
- `4` a mensagem será enviada diretamente para o log do SAPI, acredito que se usa apache ele irá para o log do Apache.

Comment: Posso adicionar em qualquer consulta de PHP?

E colocar esse codigo logo apos? 

Basicamente isso?

Comment: @PauloBoaventura em qualquer parte do código PHP, o que dependerá de você configuar a lógica para executar essa função ;)

Answer (score -6):

Recomento utilizar uma classe para criar uma estrutura de tratamento de erros da sua aplicação e dentro de um dos métodos chamar a função de log para guardar o erro ocorrido. Isso trará qualidade no seu código de evitará repetições no seu código.

Comment: Quer dizer que código de qualidade é OOP? E códigos procedurais tem qualidade inferior?

Comment: Seria legal um exemplo do código para vermos as vantagens e a qualidade obtida, em vista da função nativa.

Comment: Por favor, edite sua pergunta. A qualidade dela está baixa. Dê mais detalhes, forneça exemplos.