# Gerar logs de sistema em PHP

Tags: php, design-pattern, framework, log

Preciso gerar um documento de texto do tipo `.txt` contendo informações sobre alterações realizadas em um sistema *web*. Essas informações são sobre atividades de usuário como cadastros, alteração de cadastros, remoção de cadastros e entre outras. Como isso pode ser feito, considerando que o sistema em questão está sendo implementado com linguagem PHP?
Pensei em utilizar o padrão observer, mas não tenho certeza se é a melhor opção. Existe algum padrão de projeto ou *framework* específico para esse propósito?

Comment: Relacionado (possivel duplicata): [Como registrar um log no PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/152232/3635)

Answer (score 3):

Eu não conheço nenhum framework, mas é bem simples de fazer. Criei a função abaixo de exemplo usando o [fopen](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.fopen.php). Na função eu coloquei os arquivos separados por data. Em cada linha do arquivo tem o registo das horas em que ocorreram os logs.

```
function logs($texto){

        $hora = date("H:i:s"); // pega a hora
        $data = date("d-m-Y"); // pega o dia
        /*

            o "a+" abaixo significa:
            - Abre o arquivo para leitura e gravação; 
            - coloca o ponteiro no fim do arquivo. 
            - Se o arquivo não existir, tentar criá-lo.

        */
        $log = fopen("log/".$data.".txt", "a+");

        $escreve = fwrite($log, $hora." - ".$texto);// Escreve

        fclose($log); // Fecha o arquivo

    }
```

Quando algo acontecer no sistema, uma alteração de cadastro por exemplo, você envia essa informação usando a função `logs` criada anteriormente. Assim:

```
function alterarCadatro($nome, $email, $senha){

    ... mysqli_query...
    /*
        depois que finalizou a alteração do cadastro,
        envia a informação para a função logs
    */
    if($alterou){

        require("logs.php");
        $texto = $nome." alterou o cadastro nos campos: ".$email.",".$senha;
        logs($texto);

    }

    ...
}
```

Depois é só você criar seus padrões, por exemplo:

```
hora - tipo - local - quem
```

Ficaria assim:

```
00:25:05 - alteração - cadastro - Andrei
```

> **Nota:** Isto é apenas um exemplo, como foi citado pelo @Inkeliz, é
>   necessário que você faça filtros, satinize e/ou crie as devidas
>   seguranças ao código.

Comment: Só para notar, isto estaria vulnerável a Log Injection, se o `$nome` fosse `biscoito alterou o cadastro nos campos: bolacha \n00:00:00 - inkeliz` iria adicionar dois registros ao log, um indevidamente. Supondo que seja divido por uma quebra de linha cada registro e que o atacante saiba o padrão utilizado, de qualquer maneira é algo fácil de mitigar, melhor não dá sorte ao azar.

Comment: @Inkeliz sim.. Isso é só um exemplo. Eu não acho que eu deva satinizar ou filtrar as strings para mostrar um caminho. Ou eu devo?